# C# writes a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE at the beginning of a txt file

Tags: c#, java, character-encoding

I have a text file that is written in C# using ascii encoding and when I attempt to read the file using a java project I get a [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) character at the beginning of the file.  Has anybody ever had this happen to them?

```
private static void SavePrivateKey(object key)
{
    if (logger.IsInfoEnabled) logger.Info("SavePrivateKey - Begin");
    string privatekey = (string)key;
    string strDirName = Utility.RCTaskDirectory;
    string strFileName = "PrivateKey.PPK";
    string strKeyPathandName = Path.Combine(strDirName, strFileName);

    //if (File.Exists(strKeyPathandName))
    //{
    //    File.Create(strKeyPathandName);
    //}

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(privatekey))
    {//Save private key file
        if (!Directory.Exists(strDirName))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirName);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(strKeyPathandName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        //TODO: Save File as ASCII
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {

            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled) logger.DebugFormat("Saving the private key to {0}.", strKeyPathandName);
            sw.Write(privatekey);

            sw.Close();
            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled) logger.DebugFormat("Saved private key to {0}.", strKeyPathandName);
        }
    }
    if (logger.IsInfoEnabled) logger.Info("SavePrivateKey() - End");
}
```

Comment: No code (minimal test-case preferred) = No problem. (Issue is in how it -- the ASCII -- is written to IO. Likely ASCII inside UTF :P~)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the text is written with a BOM which is usually done when you write Unicode files... this specific character is the BOM for UTF16 files, so there must be something in your C# writing this file as UTF16...

see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it is almost certainly a Unicode Byte Order Mark.  If you have a look at the actual bytes in the file (not the characters) you can tell which encoding was used to write the file:

```
UTF-8     -> EF BB BF
UTF-16 BE -> FE FF
UTF-16 LE -> FF FE
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite normal, See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). It's a optional character, which you simply should handle. So most likely you didn't write the file correctly as ASCII, since BOM only should appear if the file is encoded as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) indicating its a UTF-16 encoded text file.

Clearly its not writing the file in true ASCII, probably your code simply copying bytes, event though they are outside of the ASCII range.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Actually, that would be UTF-16. Which is the default choice of unicode on Microsoft Windows.